# Parallelize nested looping of gridded data in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, nested

I'm struggling to find an easy example to parallelize nested loops in NDim data in Python.

As a simple example suppose we have a gridded precipitation data of dimensions (time, lat, lon), and are to find the temporal mean at each lat-lon grid point, i.e. to obtain same result as data.mean(axis=0).

```
def mean(data):
result = np.zeros(data[0,:,:].shape, dtype=np.float)
for i in range(data.shape[1]):
    for j in range(data.shape[2]):
        result[i,j] = data[:,i,j].mean()
return result
```

What would be the most elegant way to parallelize this function?

Update: The precip data can be downloaded at: https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.gpcp.html.

Test Code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import xarray
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Load data:
ds   = xarray.open_dataset('precip.mon.mean.nc')

# Select a small subset, shape is now (442, 50,50)
data = ds.precip[:,:50,:50].to_masked_array()

#define the function to compute the temporal mean at each grid point:
def mean(data):
    result = np.zeros(data[0,:,:].shape, dtype=np.float)
    for i in range(data.shape[1]):
        for j in range(data.shape[2]):
            result[i,j] = data[:,i,j].mean()
    return result

#Call the function
result = mean(data)

#A quick plot for visual reference
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(result, origin='upper',interpolation='None'); plt.colorbar()
```

My working codes involve more complex techniques (than just taking the mean), but the basic code structure is similar: nested double loop to access each grid point in order to perform analysis, and save the result as a 2D or ND array. So being able to parallelize this would be immensely beneficial.

Comment: Why do you assume your program is not elegant? Let's see the codes.

Comment: @Marichyasana Well my program is definitely serial, hence I need to parallelize it. I'll modify the question with real test data. Thanks!